# Jquery unbind event handler

Tags: c#, iframe, jquery

I have a doument which i have to load in an iframe. In that document there are several events bind with different elements like (onclick event with anchor tag) and there are some plugins also bind with elements like (cycle plugin , fancybox plugin). Now i want that when the document loads in an iframe , all events unbind. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to unbind everything in a div, you can do something like this:

```
$('div').unbind();
```

Greatings.